# exception reading http Stream

Tags: java

The code pasted below gets an exception on the line that says...
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
It's an IO exception that says: java.net.UnknownHostException: www.android.com

I checked and that is a valid URL.  I got the original code from the android docs on HttpURLConnection although I had to fix several bugs in the docs code.

Why am I getting this exception?
thanks,
Gary

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try 
            {
                URL url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");   
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());     
                readStream(in);
            } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {   
                e.printStackTrace();
            }  

            finally 
            {     
                urlConnection.disconnect();   
            } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your app have the Internet access ?try this in your AndroidManaifest.xml file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```